# How does face-down Attack Position (via Darkness Approaches) work?

Tags: yu-gi-oh

The card [Darkness Approaches](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Darkness_Approaches) has the following text:

> Discard 2 cards from your hand. Select 1 face-up monster and flip it face-down, but do not change its battle position.

Because it specifically says to not change its battle position, this would allow a face-up Attack Position monster to become a face-down Attack Position monster.

How does this work exactly? If a monster attacks a face-up Attack Position monster, what happens? Does it flip in response to the attack? Can I Flip Summon a face-up Attack Position monster? Are there other oddities that I need to be aware of?

---

*Sometime in mid-2017 (after this question was originally asked), the card text for Darkness Approaches was [errata'd](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Card_Errata:Darkness_Approaches) to no longer allow face-down Attack Position monsters:*

> Discard 2 cards from your hand. Select 1 face-up monster and change it to face-down Defense Position.

*Still, it's interesting to keep this question around for historical purposes.*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are no oddities that you need to be aware of, but you will need to remember the technical details of each action to ensure you do not breach a rule or create a tactical blunder for yourself, as explained below.

- Face-up monsters are given one (1) attack per turn. Face-down monsters are not face-up, so they cannot be used to attack.
- If a face-down attack position monster is attacked, it is flipped and stays in the same position. The damage step is worked out as if it had been face-up attack position the whole time.
- No, you cannot flip-summon an attack position monster. If the face-down monster is in attack position, it does not meet the second criteria below, and therefore is not being flip-summoned. The flip-summon is

  1. a manual change
  2. from face-down defence position
  3. to face-up attack position.

Comment: It's worth noting (for historical purposes) that flip-summoning a face-down monster did NOT have the requirement of the monster being in defense mode before Konami took over the TCG from UDE, as UDE's rulings specifically allowed flip-summoning from face-down attack position to face-up attack position. Of course, Konami has declared UDE's rulings no longer official, so any ruling by UDE that conflicts with the rules (such as the "face-down defense position" requirement for flip-summoning) is no longer valid.

Comment: That kind of edit is extremely inappropriate. If you have a comment as to the correctness or otherwise of an answer, it goes in a comment. I have rolled back your change, if it had come up in review, this would be clearly rejected as *conflicts with author intent*. @Andrew

Comment: @Nij I disagree, I believe it should be very clear that an answer is historically accurate but currently inaccurate. The accepted answer as it stands now does not show while this was true, it no longer is. Accuracy is the aim here, and a user not familiar with the card may find the question, go right to the accepted answer and get invalid information.

Comment: Then you put that in a comment and downvote until it is fixed. Don't add giant titles that presume the author incapable of responding to feedback.