# Why doesn't 'Bite Shoes' trigger the effect of 'Tragedy' in Duel Links?

Tags: yu-gi-oh

Is it a bug in Duel Links, that when I turn an enemy card from attack to defense position with *Bite Shoes*, then I can't activate the effect of *Tragedy*?

Currently I can activate it only with *Sphere Kuriboh*, *Enemy Controller*, or *Windstorm of Etaqua*.

Comment: You can also activate Tragedy by playing cards during non-Battle phases, such as "Earthquake", during your Main Phase. I have a deck that relies heavily on Tragedy and has a few cards that shift battle positions during the main phase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind, that Tragedy cannot be activated in the Damage Step.

So if Bite Shoes is flipped because it is attacked and activate its effect at the end of the Damage Stap, Tragedy cannot be activated.

Edit:
Official Source for Duel Links:
http://duellinks.gamea.co/c/tq1x92wk

Comment: Oh so this is not a bug? The other cards work because they are activated before the damage step? This makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what card you changed with *Bites Shoes*.

*Tragedy* requires that the monster which changed position from attack to defence, be face-up and under your opponent's control.

- If you changed the battle position of a monster you control, this effect does not apply, and no monsters are destroyed.
- If you changed the battle position of a defence-position monster to attack position, this effect does not apply, and no monsters are destroyed.
- If you changed the position of a face-down monster, this effect does not apply, and no monsters are destroyed.

If you changed the battle position of a face-up attack-position monster that your opponent controls, to defence position, then the effect should be activated. Only in this case have you found a bug.

Comment: Yes, there's no face-down attack position.

Comment: Ok I sent Konami a bug report.

Comment: Crouching Kitten, Face-down attack mode IS a thing, but it can only be done by the effect of a card (The only one I know of is Darkness Approaches, which flips a monster face-down without changing its position). Face-down monsters in attack position cannot be flip-summoned (Flip-summoning explicitly requires face-down defense position), but they can be switched to face-down defense position (and then flip-summoned on the next turn). If a face-down attack position monster IS attacked, it flips face-up and flip effects still trigger.

Comment: @CrouchingKitten I just recently asked [a question about face-down attack position](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/34781/3389) that results from the situation KitsuneZeta described. It's a weird situation and I see why they haven't made any cards that can do it after Darkness Approaches came out.

Comment: There is a ruling from 5/3/2017 that disallows *Darkness Approaches* from placing a monster in face-down attack position; the card errata reads ".. to face-down defence position". @KitsuneZeta

Comment: Looking forward to reading that ruling when it happens, @Nij Until that ruling happens, though, may I suggest not making a paradox with time travel. :P (Worth noting: I do see an OCG ruling dating from March 25, 2017, but not one from May 3rd, 2017)

Comment: 5/3/2017 is March 5th, 2017. The 2 didn't succeed on touchscreen. Don't be a North American-centric ass regardless.